# iPhone, how can I evalute whether a text property is equal to a define'd string?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have the following define'd constant set up.

```
#define EndDateNotSpecified "None"
```

But I can't seem to evaluate it, I've tried

```
if (btnEndDate.titleLabel.text != EndDateNotSpecified) {
```

and

```
if (btnEndDate.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:EndDateNotSpecified) {
```

I get compiler problems with each.

Comment: Generally, I think you should learn the basic Objective-C, your code doesn't look like a obj-c code. No bracket, no @"" for String:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an @ for the string, remember to add this to every string constant:

```
#define EndDateNotSpecified @"None"
```

Answer (score 1):

Close, just missing brackets around the method call, like

```
if ([btnEndDate.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:EndDateNotSpecified]) {
```

And in the future, it generally helps if you tell us what the specific compiler error was.

Answer (score 1):

In objective C, you have to call a method in [] so the second one should be:
`if ([btnEndDate.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:EndDateNotSpecified]) {`

Don't use this because it will not always give correct result when you only compare the NSString pointer object

`if (btnEndDate.titleLabel.text != EndDateNotSpecified) {`

Generally, I think you should learn the basic Objective-C, your code doesn't look like a obj-c code. No [], no @"" for String:(